# Loading csv file with 100 millions records to dynamodb

Tags: csv, hive, load, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to load massive data to dynamodb service.
My csv contains 100 millions records.
each record contains 4 fields (3 of string type and another of BIGINT type).
I created 1 table on dynamo db:
1. with partition key and sort key and two LSI.
2. with 10000 WCU

I tried several approach with no success:

1. wrote a script which executes parallel requests with batch_write boto3 api method.
2. create EMR cluster, load csv data to hive table, map hive table to dynamo table and then load from hive table to dynamodb table via 15 parallel processes.

statistics:
approach 1: 2 minutes for loading 10K records
approach 2: 3 hrs and 20 min loading 26 millions records

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: When you say "with no success", it does not load (or error) or it too slow for your liking?

Comment: too slow :) sorry for not being cleared